# how to convert dateformat in php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I get the data from database, which gives me date in a format like `2014-01-06 06:13:06`. I want to convert this date into the format `Jan 6th 2014`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$query="SELECT Min(transaction_date) as start,Max(transaction_date) as end from transactions";
$result1= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$ors1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$date= $ors1['start'];
echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
?>
```

Comment: `echo date( 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y', strtotime($ors1['start']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
 <?php 
    $query="SELECT Min(transaction_date) as start,Max(transaction_date) as end from transactions";
    $result1= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $ors1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    $date= $ors1['start'];
    echo date('dS M Y' ,strtotime($date));
 ?>
```

Reference url : [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` to get a timestamp from string representation of the time.
Then use `date` to format the timestamp into any format you want.

e.g.

```
$formatted_date = date('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y', strtotime('2014-01-06 06:13:06 '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```
<?php
echo 'Current time: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$format = 'Y-m-!d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

$format = '!d';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '15');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Current time: 2010-04-23 10:29:35
Format: Y-m-d; 2009-02-15 10:29:35
Format: Y-m-d H:i:s; 2009-02-15 15:16:17
Format: Y-m-!d H:i:s; 1970-01-15 15:16:17
Format: !d; 1970-01-15 00:00:00
```

for more info:https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this itself in `MySQL`

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start, '%M %D %Y') as start_formatted,
    DATE_FORMAT(end, '%M %D %Y') as end_formatted
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Min(transaction_date) as start, Max(transaction_date) as end
    from
        transactions) t;
```

**Example**

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M %D %Y');
+-------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M %D %Y') |
+-------------------------------+
| January 27th 2014             |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$date= $ors1['start'];
$objdate=new DateTime($date);
echo date_format($objdate, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```